# How to change the backButtonItem title on a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I feel daft asking this question, but I haven't been able to get this to work. I have a NavController->TableViewController->WebViewController. I'm trying to change the title of the backButton on the WVC from the default "Back" to "Reference".

This should be a simple matter of setting the text property of the Back button either in Storyboard (which isn't working) or in code of my WebViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Reference";
```

Is this just a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Select Navigationbar in TableViewController and set Back btn  title attribute inspector.

Comment: Jaleel. Thanks, I did that but it's still the default. Bug perhaps?

Comment: What version of xCode and simulator you are using?

Comment: Xcode 6.3. Simulator 8.3

Answer (score 0):

You should set it in your `TableViewController`, not in your `WebViewContorller`

Comment: I did. Still nothing. This is driving me nuts. Why can't the simple Storyboard  Back Button field work?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your tableviewController

```
 UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reference" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Screen shot

[image]

From document

> If you want to specify a custom image or title for the back button, you can assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or image) to this property instead.

Comment: in viewDidLoad or viewWillLoad?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` is ok

Comment: Nice screenshot. Jealous cause I still got "Back". I put it in viewDidLoad in TableViewController.

Comment: So, it's working in another tab, but not the one I need it to work in. Any ideas? I'm not calling viewWillLoad or other view methods.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had added a grey activity indicator in a small view in the nav bar of the WVC. After I removed it, the code worked fine. Thanks @Leo, @Jacky, @Jaleel!

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reference" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.